# Destroying Runnable in android

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler

I am using the following code to access a url:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{
   public void run() 
   {
       img.setImageBitmap(returnBitmap("fromurl")); 
       handler.postDelayed(this, 50);  
   }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

I observed that if the server is not up the app takes ages to close correctly if I hit the back button. Is there anyway way I could speed up the exit procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    private boolean killMe=false;
    public void run() {
        //some work
        if(!killMe) {

            img.setImageBitmap(returnBitmap("fromurl"));
            handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
        }
    }
    public void kill(){
        killMe=true;
    }
};

ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable longRunningTask = new Runnable();

// submit task to threadpool:
Future longRunningTaskFurure = threadPoolExecutor.submit(longRunningTask);

... ...
// At some point in the future, if you want to kill the task:
longRunningTaskFuture.cancel(true);
... ...
```

Comment: Can I just put in the the onDestroy() method as the only time I want to kill it is when the application stops. Also it says:`type mismatch: cannot convert from ExecutorService to ThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ExecutorService to ThreadPoolExecutor

how to fix this?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. The important logic is stored in `runnable`, which is never used. And `longRunningTask` is a Runnable with no interesting contents. Maybe should be `.. threadPoolExecutor.submit(runnable);`

Answer (score 1):

Runnables will exit automatically when finished with their `run()` method. If you are employing a loop to do some work, the solution that Jay Ho suggested will help exit from the loop cleanly. If you want to prevent the `Handler` from executing the runnable (before it posts) you can use `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`[1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages%28java.lang.Object%29) to clear the queue. Placing it in `onDestroy()` is your best bet.  Otherwise, you're on your own. Once you've spawned a thread, you're at the mercy of the Android operating system to terminate it once its done.

Side note:  I've run into problems like this before, and it's usually a call to a system service or the implementation of a Broadcast Listener or Alarm that mucks up the exit process.